# Tooltip message text and background color

Tags: flutter, tooltip

I have Image.asset wrapped on Tooltip

```
Padding(
     padding: edgeInsets,
     child: Tooltip(preferBelow: false, message: "Miejsca parkingowe ogólnodostępne", child: Image.asset("assets/icons/garage.png", width: _iconSize, height: _iconSize,)),
),
```

How to set tooltip message text color and background color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, `Tooltip` does'not provide a parameter to change these behaviors but

`Tooltip` takes the your theme

```
final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    final ThemeData darkTheme = ThemeData(
      brightness: Brightness.dark,
      textTheme: theme.brightness == Brightness.dark ? theme.textTheme : theme.primaryTextTheme,
      platform: theme.platform,
    );
```

so you can create theme in your `MaterialApp` (Text color works but backgroundColor does'not work in my app, you can give a try)

```
return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
        primaryTextTheme: TextTheme(
          body1: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.blue,
          )
        ),
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: ......
```

or

This is `Tooltip`  code may be you can change from the source code of the `Tooltip` which is an bad solution.

```dart
    return Positioned.fill(
      child: IgnorePointer(
        child: CustomSingleChildLayout(
          delegate: _TooltipPositionDelegate(
            target: target,
            verticalOffset: verticalOffset,
            preferBelow: preferBelow,
          ),
          child: FadeTransition(
            opacity: animation,
            child: Opacity(
              opacity: 0.9,
              child: ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: height),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: darkTheme.backgroundColor,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0),
                  ),
                  padding: padding,
                  child: Center(
                    widthFactor: 1.0,
                    heightFactor: 1.0,
                    child: Text(message, style: darkTheme.textTheme.body1),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: THX. Text color works but backgroundColor does'not work for me too :)

Comment: If you are looking to change the background color of Tooltip you can use the 'decoration' parameter it has, and just pass a BoxDecoration with your custom colors and whatnot. Mind you that BoxDecoration does not have rounded corners by default but you can easily add it again with the BorderRadius parameter.

Answer (score 4):

You can change color of tootip with textStyle attribute. and background color of tooltip with decoration attribute.

```
    Padding(
         padding: edgeInsets,
         child: Tooltip(textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),text preferBelow: false, message: "Miejsca parkingowe ogólnodostępne", 
         child: Image.asset("assets/icons/garage.png", width: _iconSize, height: _iconSize,)),
     ),
```

Answer (score 3):

`ToolTip` supports the `decoration` named argument, so you don't need to change your top-level theme.

```
/// Specifies the tooltip's shape and background color.
///
/// If not specified, defaults to a rounded rectangle with a border radius of
/// 4.0, and a color derived from the [ThemeData.textTheme] if the
/// [ThemeData.brightness] is dark, and [ThemeData.primaryTextTheme] if not.
final Decoration decoration;
```

However, there are other widgets, that include the `ToolTip` widget in their `build` method, for example, `IconButton` where they only support a `tooltip` as a `String`, so there's no way currently to change the `tooltip` style for the `IconButton`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [TooltipThemeData](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TooltipThemeData-class.html) and set it into your top-level ThemeData.

```
TooltipThemeData(
  textStyle: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.white,
    fontFamily: "Questrial",
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
  ),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.indigo,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible set the color of an individual icon's tooltip by setting TooltipTheme as the parent widget, for example as follows:

```
TooltipTheme(
  data: TooltipThemeData(
    textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.white),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.blue[300],
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
    ),
  ),
  child: IconButton(
    tooltip: 'Icon Title',
    icon: Icon(Icons.analytics, color: Colors.black, size: 50),
    onPressed: () {}
  ),
)
```

As per the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TooltipTheme-class.html).